# Measuring generic delegates / wrapping GetDelegateForFunctionPointer

Tags: windows, generics, .net-core, .net-6.0

I'm using generic FunctionLoader from my original QA, which includes more code and usage, here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514895/492624

I'd like to return function, that has the same signature, but internally measures the original delegate call.

This must be implemented/usable in `net6.0` framework (Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web sdk), and can be limited (as the FunctionLoader already is) to Windows platform.

so something like should be the wrapping delegate function

```cs
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var rtn = T();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"elapsed: {sw.Elapsed}"
return rtn;
```

Snippet from original QA, which i'd like to modify:

```cs
public static T LoadFunction<T>(string dllPath, string functionName)
    {
        // normalize
        if (!Path.IsPathFullyQualified(dllPath))
        {
            dllPath = Path.GetFullPath(dllPath);
        }
        // Get preloaded or load the library on-demand
        IntPtr hModule = LoadedLibraries.GetOrAdd(
            dllPath,
            valueFactory: (string dllPath) =>
            {
                IntPtr loaded = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
                if (loaded == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new DllNotFoundException($"Library not found in path {dllPath}");
                }
                return loaded;
            }
        );
        // Load function
        var functionAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, functionName);
        if (functionAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new EntryPointNotFoundException($"Function {functionName} not found in {dllPath}");
        }
        var originalDelegate = (T)(object)(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(functionAddress, typeof(T)));
        // Return wrapper, that has the same delegate signature (T) but internally measures and logs the elapsed, before returning the value to caller
        return ???
    }
```